# mysqlclient with mingw

Tags: cmake, mingw, libmysql

I want to use libmysqlclient on a project cross compiled to Windows via mingw.
In order to link my program, I need "mysqlclient.a" but I'm not able to get it.

I tried to create makefiles for mingw on windows for mysql client, but the configuration step fail.

---

I was finaly able to build it... using mingw on Windows.

Here are the steps:

1. Install cygwin
2. Install packages make, gcc, g++, cmake and cygidn in your cygwin
3. Download & uncompress libmysql source code
4. Edit file strings/dtoa.c and replace all occurance of `dtoa` to something else like `_dtoa` to prevent conflicts
5. cd to the package base
6. type cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" in mingw
7. make
8. make install
9. edit C:\cygwin\usr\local\mysql\include\mysql.h and add `#include <winsock.h> /* Bug win32 */` after `#define _mysql_h`
10. You can get your files in "C:\cygwin\usr\local\mysql"

I get "libmysqlclient.a" and "liblibmysql.dll.a" and I link my program with them but I still get linker error. What's wrong ?
But I still get linking error !

`strings libmysqlclient.a | grep _mysql_ping` returns a result while the linker complains about undefined reference to `_mysql_ping@4'

Answer (score 0):

MinGW and Cygwin are often not compatible. You have to build a MySQL client in a 100% MinGW environment.

Comment: Can you be more precise than "often" ?

Answer (score 0):

With MinGW, you are encouraged to use Windows *.lib files.

Download and install the [MySQL Connector/C](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) binary for your Windows platform (32bit or 64bit)

Then compile and link your program accordingly:

```
g++ myprog.cpp \
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" \
-L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib" -lmysql
```